# C++ how to implement a growing stack?

Tags: c++, stack

my task is to implement a stack program, however modified to include a dynamic, growing array.If there is an  attempt to push data onto a full stack a new array of twice the current size is created. The data from the old stack is copied to the new stack and the only stack is deleted. Each time the stack doubles a message to console should be printed in the form Stack doubled from old_size to new_size. Below is my attempt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int count = 0; //stores the indexed number
int capacity = 0; //stores the allocated size
int *myStack = NULL; //stores the data from file

//function declarations/prototypes
void push(const int &aString);
int top();
void pop();
bool isEmpty();
void cleanup();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    push(1);
    push(1);
    push(1);
    push(1);
    push(1);
    pop();
    pop();
    push(1);
    cleanup();

    cout << "The Stack contains " << count << " entries" << endl;

    return 0;
}

void push(const int &value) {

    if (count == capacity) {
       int newCapacity = (capacity == 0) ? 2 : (capacity * 2);
        int *newStack = new int[newCapacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            newStack[i] = myStack[i];
        }
        delete[] myStack;
        myStack = newStack;
        cout << "Stack doubled from " << capacity << " to " << newCapacity << endl;
        capacity = newCapacity;
    }
    
    myStack[count] = value;
    ++count; 

}

int top() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        return int();
    }
    return myStack[count-1]; //return top value
}

void pop() {
    if (count > 0) {
        --count; //decrement count for stack
        myStack[count];
    }
}

bool isEmpty() {
    return (count < 1);
}

void cleanup() {
    capacity = count = 0;
    delete[] myStack;
    myStack = NULL;
}
```

The stack has an inital value of 2 (can hold 2 values). A sample input(which is the input i have hardcoded using the push and pop functions) and output is shown below.

Input(as shown in my main)

```
 //with an inital array size of 2
  push 1 
  push 1 
  push 1 
  push 1 
  push 1 
  pop 
  pop 
  push 1
```

output

```
Stack doubled from 2 to 4.
Stack doubled from 4 to 8.
Stack contains 4 entries.
```

This is the output i receive instead of the one shown above

```
Stack doubled from 0 to 2
Stack doubled from 2 to 4
Stack doubled from 4 to 8
The stack contains 0 entries
```

How can I fix my program so I get the right output?

Comment: `int newCapacity = (capacity == 0) ? 20 : (capacity * 2);` typo? But note also that you `cout` *after* the assignment `capacity = newCapacity` so you'll never see `Stack doubled from 2 to 4`. Finally you call `cleanup()` before trying to print how many elements are in the stack, which resets `count` to `0`.

Comment: @NathanPierson whats the typo?

Comment: `20` instead of `2`.

Comment: Start with a debugger.

Comment: @NathanPierson ah yup noted! ive changed it if you'd like to see my new output

Comment: @NathanPierson oh wow all my issues were because of that typo!! thankyou

Comment: Glad I could help.